# error using simple kdeplot example from the doc

Tags: jupyter-notebook, seaborn

I want to execute the following example from the doc in a jupyter notebook : https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html

```
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
sns.kdeplot(data=tips, x="total_bill", hue="time")
```

But I get an error :

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Sun'
```

I use seaborn 0.10.1 and python 3.8.3

It works when I use :

```
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
sns.kdeplot(data=tips.total_bill)
```

But in this case, I can't use hue with the time column.

Answer (score 4):

I fixed it by upgrading seaborn to 0.11 using :

```
pip install seaborn --upgrade
```

With conda, the version didn't upgrade after 0.10.1